# how to set and unset javascript files for specifc path aliases in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, javascript

I am trying to set particular javascript files for a specific node page by getting the path alias. like this:

```
$path=drupal_get_path_alias();  
if($path == 'about-us')
  drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . "/page-download.js");
```

which it doesnt work. 
But when i add the particular javascript file to my .info file it works. 
Also in other pages i will have to unset some of the javascript files if the above does not work but still unsetting javascripts does not work.

```
unset($vars['js']['all']['page-download.js']);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as adding the JS file goes it probably depends where you're calling that code from. If you're calling it directly in a template file it's probably happening too late in the page build.

A `hook_preprocess_page()` implementation would probably be a good place for it (as would `hook_init()` and probably a bunch of others). You can also use [`request_uri()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/request_uri/7) to check the current path without incurring a lookup for the alias.

```
function MYMOUDLE_preprocess_page(&$vars) {  
  if (request_uri() == '/about-us') {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . "/page-download.js");
  }
}
```

If for whatever reason you can't get that to work, you can remove a JS file by implementing [`hook_js_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7):

```
function MYMODULE_js_alter(&$js) {
  if ($some_condition) {
    $js_path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . "/page-download.js";
    if (isset($js[$js_path])) {
      unset($js[$js_path]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you! I am calling that code from mytheme_preprocess page in the template.php file. So i will have to create a module to unset the unwanted javascript files in specific path aliases?

Comment: If I remember rightly you should be able to use `hook_js_alter()` in your theme, but I can't find anything on the docs page that says that you can. Best way would be to try...if not, a custom module it is :)

Comment: Implemented it now as a hook_js_alter(&$javascript) with no luck. I was just wondering if the parameter of the function is correct. Because your code above is using MYMODULE_js_alter(&$js) {
instead of   hook_js_alter(&$javascript) that drupal suggests (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7)here. So i guess i will have to implemented it as a module.

Comment: `$js`/`$javascript` is just the name of the variable to be used in the scope of that function. As long as you're using the same name in the rest of the function (e.g. `unset($javascript[$js_path]);`) there's absolutely no difference. Remember to clear the caches after adding the new hook or it won't be picked up. If you want to make sure the hook is running, add `drupal_set_message('test');` to the function. If you see the message, it's running, and the problem will probably be that Drupal can't find the JS file at the path you're giving it

Comment: yes i have it all to $javascript variable. I cleared the cache and no message appeared. I tried echo to the path as well with no luck:( I dont think my javascript file path is wrong since i have the file inside /sites/all/themes/ninesixty  so the path is correct. Maybe a time of thinking for a module?

Comment: Yeah it definitely works in a module (I've just tried it) so that might be the way to go

Comment: am i doing something wrong and it doesnt work for me? I have created a module with two files one .module file and one with .info file. It appears correctly in my modules list, i enabled it but the javascript file is still there when i am trying to view page source. :S The only think i have done was to take the function as you told me (the function hook_js_alter) and place it inside the .module file. With no luck!! Do i have to do something else as well?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4421/discussion-between-nicole-and-clive)